# Expected 1 argument(s) for "int system(const char *)"; had 2 instead

Tags: c++, echo

```
void TATTDataset::AckErrHandler(const NDataString& ErrMsg)
{
    system("echo ErrMsg: %s >> err", (const char *)ErrMsg);
    ...... code .......
}
```

What does this error message mean? How do I resolve it? ErrMsg.toCString() doesn't help either. Any suggestion?

EDIT:

I edited the code as suggested -

```
String s;    
Char *tmpStr = ErrMsg.ToCString();
s.Format("echo ErrMsg: %s >> err",tmpStr);    
system(s);
```

Still I get:
 Cannot initialize 'char *' with 'const char *'.
 Char *tmpStr = ErrMsg.ToCString();

Comment: declare tmpStr as const: `const char *tmpStr =...`

Answer (score 1):

The [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) call has really just one argument. What you are trying to do is to let `system()` act like `printf()`, which is obviously not the way it was designed to.

You cant try to use a string class which can do some parsing or make a temporary buffer and use [sprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: <quote>obviously not the way it was designed to.</quote>: obvious is a subjective term. If it was obvious then the poster --obviously-- would not have made the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned system() takes only one argument (a string).

If ErrMsg.toCString() returns a MFC CString then you can try this:

```
void TATTDataset::AckErrHandler(const NDataString& ErrMsg)
{
    CString s;
    s.Format("echo ErrMsg: %s >> err", ErrMsg.toCString());
    system(s);
    ...... code .......
}
```

Comment: Char *str;
const char* ToCString() const { return str; }

Answer (score 0):

the system function has only one argument, but you passed in two.

```
1st argument: "echo ErrMsg: %s >> err"
2nd argument: (const char *)ErrMsg
```

you resolve it by passing only one argument, or redifining system() to accept two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 2 arguments to system it expects one

The 2 are
    "echo ErrMsg: %s >> err"

```
(const char *)ErrMsg
```

I suspect you meant so combine them e.g. use snprintf

Although if this is actual code I would output the error message to a file directly rather than use system e.g. fprintf